# SAS, date manipulation

Tags: date, sas

```
%let enddt = intnx('month',today(),0);
%let data = DataName_%sysfunc(intnx(month,%sysfunc(date()),-1),yymmn6);
%let intdt  = intnx('month',today(),-7);
%let start = intnx('month',today(),-25);
```

How can I write the other 3 macro variables based on the first one (enddt)
For example, As of today, intdt=enddt-7, start=enddt-25. Data=DataName_201604.

If I change the enddt to intnx('month',today(),-1), then the other three will automatically changed. intdt=enddt-7, start=enddt-25. Data=DataName_201603.

Now if I want the date go back to 2 month, I have to do it manually like this:

```
%let enddt = intnx('month',today(),-2);
%let data = DataName_%sysfunc(intnx(month,%sysfunc(date()),-3),yymmn6);
%let intdt  = intnx('month',today(),-9);
%let start = intnx('month',today(),-27);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to loop over a date range with your 4 variables fixed time distances apart from each other. You need to create a macro function that redefines the 4 variables each iteration, something like this should get you on the right track:

```
%macro dateloop();
    %do i=0 %to 10;
        %let enddt = %sysfunc(intnx(month,%sysfunc(date()),-&i),yymmn6);
        %let data = DataName_%sysfunc(intnx(month,%sysfunc(date()),-&i-1),yymmn6);
        %let intdt  = %sysfunc(intnx(month,%sysfunc(date()),-&i-7),yymmn6);
        %let start = %sysfunc(intnx(month,%sysfunc(date()),-&i-25),yymmn6);

        %put enddt = &enddt, data = &data, intdt = &intdt, start = &start;

        /**** do your work here ****/

    %end;
%mend;

%dateloop();
```

Comment: This is totally irrelevant to the question being asked. He's not trying to loop over macro variables, he's trying to write one as a function of others.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you're not setting intdt and start to have anything to do with enddt. Try replacing "today()" with "&enddt."

For example:

```
%let intdt  = intnx('month',&enddt.,-7);
```